# How do you add two zero vector ? Is there any meaning in it ? $\vec{0}+\vec{0}$ =?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Is there anything interesting from math point of view when adding two zero length vectors ? Do you get same vector that points in all directions same way ?

$\vec{0}+\vec{0}$ =?

Comment: You get $\overrightarrow{0}$. Not that interesting, but it is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by well defined ?

Comment: $\vec{0}+\vec{v}=\vec{v}$ for any $\vec{v}$. Now let $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: Nothing plus nothing means nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about what zero vector is: a vector without length, so zero vector plus zero vector is like this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0+0\\
0+0\\
\vdots\\
0+0\\
\vdots\\
0+0
\end{pmatrix}=
\vec{0}$$

Answer (score 3):

No. It's just like adding zero and zero.

Answer (score 1):

The zero vector *is* a vector, so you can add the zero vector to it and get the same vector out, just like you can with any other vector.